# iOS NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I've a conceptual question — do I always have to use the `standardUserDefaults` API when accessing `NSUserDefaults`?

I am saving a lot of settings/flags/`NSCoding` info in my app for a variety of things. But for some of these things, it doesn't feel natural for me to be bothering the `standardUserDefaults`. I am wondering if I could potentially create a new `NSUserDefaults` entity for managing certain type of information that I want to store.

Just for an example — I am using some background `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`s and I want to save some relationship data between the `downloadTask` and the actual user for which the download task was initiated. I am saving that data to `NSUserDefaults`. I just am not sure if accessing `NSUserDefaults` for this (and other things) is the way to go!

[Maybe I didn't explain this right. Sorry!]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I understand, there's no need to specifically create a new user defaults file for the specific purpose of classification of data.

The NSUserDefaults can be as large as any system file and the data dump can be adjusted accordingly. In case one needs a new defaults, please see Catfish_Man's answer. Also, this is specifically for the case when you deal with a certain group of apps.

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is not the right solution for what you described.

NSUserDefaults is actually for a very narrow and particular purpose. It is mainly meant to interact with users, let them set their preferences and get those preferences persisted.

It is not meant to be used as any type of general purpose storage.

For what you want, you can always use a usual NSDictionary etc for that. If you need it to be accessible from multiple places, leave it on the application delegate or create a singleton class. If you need it to be persisted across runs, use something like SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To save simple flags across sessions, I need to be using SQLite? That's such insane overkill.

Comment: It all depends on what you have, you know the situation the best and you are the best person to decide.

Comment: Well lets just say the problem in hand is the one I described above. Saving username for every user for which you requested a profile photo from the server.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is use `[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:]` to create separate `NSUserDefaults` storage.

Just doing `[[NSUserDefaults alloc] init]` will get you the same storage as `standardUserDefaults`.